# How to insert garbage characters into mysql table via JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, character-encoding, httpclient

I am working on an application that `consumes json` supplied by another webapp. Using `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` to retrieve data and then store the relevant data into mysql tables.

Something like this:

```
URI uri = builder.build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpget);
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse
    .getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    //process it
}
```

**Response headers**:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1, Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,private,must-revalidate,max-stale=0,post-check=0,pre-check=0, 
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, 
Pragma: no cache, 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=26E4AC5C0EF37BA53B736DF9B0F903FD; 
Path=/, 
Content-Type: application/x-javascript;
charset=UTF-8, 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked, 
Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2013 12:10:06 GMT, 
Connection: close]
```

The code works fine for normal data in response and populates the respective columns. But in some cases, response contains garbage characters which fails to be inserted into the database table. 
One such example of garbage data:

```
P . 1989-1990 ݋ ݇�� ���� �� ����J� ᣇ¹I� ������K� �PM�H�� ��옉� �I� ���� ܬ� �E� �������� ��  ���J� ��I�  �E� �� ��K� ܬ�芪�� ��A ��A�. �E����� ��� ��F�� ��M� ����� �������� �I�  �E� �� ��K�, ������ ����O� ��� ...
```

The insertion fails with a nasty SQLException:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF1\xA3\x87\xB9I\xEF...' for column 'dataSet' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:233)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    ... 5 more
```

**Any suggestion on how can I enter such data into the database table? Please advice.**

Some platform information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
MYSQL Version: 5.5.32 
//DB Details
character_set_client:latin1
character_set_connection:latin1
character_set_database:latin1
character_set_filesystem:binary
character_set_results:latin1
character_set_server:latin1
character_set_system:utf8
```

---

### EDIT

I would like to stress on the fact that if same code and database server are moved onto a Windows environment, they work fine. No errors. However they fails on a *nix environment. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is interpreting your "garbage data" as text instead of arbitrary binary data. You can avoid that by using a binary datatype for the `dataSet` column, for example `VARBINARY` instead of `VARCHAR`, or `BLOB` instead of `TEXT`.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. It works perfect. However, I have a lot of columns that are populated and changing the data type of all the columns might not be an option. (I will have to confirm it with my superiors). Thanks again :)

Comment: Changing the character encoding of the column to `utf8mb4` should also work: MySQL's `utf8` encoding only goes up to 3-byte characters, and here the program is trying to insert a character that requires 4 bytes. But since the data is ultimately not composed of characters I think it's more appropriate to use a binary data type.